# OffscreenPageLimit behaviour for ViewPager from Accompanist

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I am using HorizontalViewPager from [Accompanist](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/) to show an image in each page of the viewpager. I am loading images with Coil. Here's the code:

```
val pagerState = rememberPagerState()

HorizontalPager(count = photos.size, state = pagerState) {
    idx ->
    photos[idx].let { cur ->
        Image(
            painter = rememberImagePainter(url),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier - Modifier.fillMaxSize(), 
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight,
            alignment = Alignment.Center
        )
    }
}
```

It is working fine. But, Images are being loaded only after the page is opened. I was wondering if there is a way to preload the content of the adjacent pages of viewpager before they are opened.

[ViewPager](https://ViewPager%20from%20AndroidX) from AndroidX offers similar behavior with `setOffscreenPageLimit` method.

Comment: Turns out old versions of the accompanist-pager had a offScreenLimit parametr which was [removed](https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/6547266f2577d05353c86c1586c6466f00aadb6f/docs/pager.md#horizontalpager--verticalpager) in 0.19.0 version. What do I do now?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69602438/3585796) answer your question?

Comment: @PylypDukhov I gave it a try, but the loading time is still not that short. During loading time page is blank and it is noticable

Comment: I noticed that If I slightly swipe the current page to open the edge of the next page, then the next page starts loading, I wonder if this can help me to do some hack

Comment: Using my method you can start loading next page (or a couple of pages) image from the current page, is this what you're trying?

Comment: Yes, I got your method and tried it. It is loading the images into memory (at least thats what documentation says), but the time taken to load the image from memory into Image view is still noticable somehow

Comment: I was able to reproduce this, I think it is a bug and should be reported to Coil. The `offscreenLimit` was removed [during the rewrite](https://github.com/google/accompanist/pull/678) to lazy views, this solved some problems, but `offscreenLimit` became impossible to maintain. Perhaps someday it will be rewritten again, but for now you will have to live without it.

Comment: @PylypDukhov Funny but when I tried your method inside the Pager block and loaded the next page image simultaneously with the current page image, it is working :). Thanks!